# edit jsp and build show error

Tags: jsp, tomcat

I was working with Java, Struts 2, Spring and Hibernate project in eclipse.. The project is deployed on Tomcat. It works fine until I change some JSP in Eclipse and build using Ant build. When I restart Tomcat, it shows error.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP


java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\work\Catalina\localhost\test\org\apache\jsp\login_jsp.java (Access is denied)
    java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make sure that the user used to run Tomcat has read and write permissions to the directory mentioned in the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try build option of project menu, it throws error because it does not find class file of the jsp.

Comment: The java file that is generated from the JSP can't be written.